# Difference between し and て形

Tags: word-choice, て-form, particle-し

例えば、

> この掃除機は小さいし、軽いし、それに音が静かです。
>   この掃除機は小さくて、軽くて、それに音が静かです。

Answer (score 1):

「この掃除機は小さく**て**、軽く**て**、それに音が静かです。」で使われている「～て」は並列の「て」で、「小さい」「軽い」「音が静か」の三つの形容(動)詞を並べて述べているものです。

もう一方の「この掃除機は小さい**し**、軽い**し**、それに音が静かです。」で使われている「～し」は、類似の事柄を並べて示す役割を持っています。この場合は、「小さい」「軽い」「音が静か」という三つの長所・良いところを並べて、「小さい、そのうえ/さらに軽い、そのうえ/さらに音も静かです。（だから/それほど良いものですよ。）」という感じで、この掃除機の良さをより強調するニュアンスがあります。

「～て」は、類似しない事柄を並べて、「この鏡餅は、白くて、丸くて、大きい。」のように言うこともできます。でも、これを「～し」でつなげて、「この鏡餅は、白いし、丸いし、大きい。」とすると、ちょっと変です。

また、「～し」を使うと、少しカジュアル・口語的な感じになります。